# Skaffold always pulls base image

Tags: docker, skaffold

When developing locally, is skaffold supposed to always pull the base image for the image built in

```
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: XXX
    docker:
      target: build
```

In my Dockerfile I have a `FROM X` which I can see when running `docker images`.

I have set the environment variables for minikube `eval $(minikube docker-env)` and I've tried setting the `cacheFrom` property under `docker` in the `skaffold.yaml`.

Any ideas on how to get skaffold to stop pulling images every time you run `skaffold dev`?

Comment: The Docker build is expected to show each of the steps from the Dockerfile. A Docker build will not pull the base image when it is already present _unless_ you set `pullParent: true` in your `skaffold.yaml`.  (And just to be sure, be sure to run `(eval $(minikube docker-env); docker images)` to look for the pulled images.)

May I ask: how do you know that the base image is being re-pulled on each `skaffold dev`?

Comment: Since eventually it fails on the docker hub rate limit. Since I'm a free user that's 200 images I think. Another complication is that I'm using the Cloud Code intellij plugin to run skaffold. I'll try running from terminal to see if the same problem arises